# The .makeCopy () function does not duplicate gSite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites, google-workspace

My code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  file.makeCopy(folder ); 
 }
```

effect:

Access denied: DriveApp. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically Delete Files from Google Drive Older than n days - Access denied: DriveApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088579/automatically-delete-files-from-google-drive-older-than-n-days-access-denied)

Comment: I have not problem with the api authentication
doc and sheet works

Comment: Your code worked for me.  The only modification I made was to removed the brackets in your ID references.  I also removed them from your question.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to copy the files of Google Site which has the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.site` using a script.

If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, in the current stage, it cannot achieved it. I think that file with `application/vnd.google-apps.site` is a special from the following specification.

1. When a file of `application/vnd.google-apps.site` is created, `canCopy` of the property of capabilities which is a metadata becomes `false` as the default.
2. `canCopy` is not directly writable. So it cannot modify to `true`.
3. Files of `application/vnd.google-apps.site` cannot be created by the script and API.

Because of above situation, the files of `application/vnd.google-apps.site` cannot be copied by the script and API.

#### Note:

- Although the files of `application/vnd.google-apps.site` cannot be copied by the script and API, it can manually copy.

#### Reference:

- [Metadata of Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

If this information was not useful for you, I apologize.